# Linear Mixed Effects Model in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

I am trying to understand the outputs from the lme() function in R.

I have the following model:

\begin{equation}
X_i(t_{ij}) = \eta + Z_i(t_{ij})w_i + \epsilon_{ij},
\end{equation}

where $\eta$ is the mean, $Z_i(t_{ij}) = [1, \log(t_{ij})]$, $w_i = (w_{0i}, w_{1i})' \sim N(0, \Sigma_w)$, $\epsilon_{ij} \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$, and

\begin{equation}
 \Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_1^2 & \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2  \\
    \rho\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2 
  \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

The lme() function can be used for this (I do not have a question about the fitting of the model). Using

```
model$coef$fixed
model$coefficients$random
```

I can extract the estimated coefficients for the fixed and random coefficients.

I think `model$sigma` gives me the estimate for $\sigma$ but what is `model$varFix`? Is it the standard error of the fixed coefficient squared?

How do I extract the estimates for $\rho$, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$? What is `model$apVar`?

Comment: Try `vcov(model_name)` which will give you $\Sigma$ above.  All elements can then be deduced, if nothing else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `getVarcov()` function to obtain the estimated covariance matrix of the random effect, e.g.,

```
library("nlme")
fm <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
getVarCov(fm)
```

Comment: Do you know what `model$varFix` and `model$apVar` are?